# Trying to limit the amount be shown in a mysql result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores id, item, food type, image and price

I want to limit the result to one of each type sold in the store e.g. dog food, cat food, dvd in descending order
Example of what is held in mysql database
table: Nunca

```
id      item                    type        image   price
=========================================================
1       Pedigree Pouches        dog food    img1    $4.99
2       Cesar Classic Selection dog food    img2    $3.99
3       Meaty Strips Chicken    dog food    img3    $2.99
4       Jelly Fish Selection    cat food    img4    $1.99
5       Bananas                 fruit       img5    $2.84
6       Celery                  vegetables  img6    $5.99
7       Apple                   fruit       img7    $0.95
8       Pineapple Juice         Soft drink  img8    $0.99
9       Oranges                 fruit       img9    $1.99
10      Cabbage                 vegetables  img10   $0.99
11      Suicide Squad           dvd         img11   $12.99
```

The final result should look like this from the query

```
id      item                    type        image   price
==========================================================
11      Suicide Squad           dvd         img11   $12.99
10      Cabbage                 vegetables  img10   $0.99
9       Oranges                 fruit       img9    $1.99
8       Pineapple Juice         Soft drink  img8    $0.99
4       Jelly Fish Selection    cat food    img4    $1.99
3       Meaty Strips Chicken    dog food    img3    $2.99
```

I have tried various mysql queries, but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from t where 
id in(select max(t.id) id from t group by t.type) 
order by id desc
```

I guess there can be window or join alternatives but this one seemed fitting for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has hit the nail right on the head

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A typical method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select n.*
from nunca n
where n.id = (select max(n2.id) from nunca n2 where n2.type = n.type);
```

This will choose the last row of each type.

Comment: This is only producing one record, that is
id      item                    type        image   price

11      Suicide Squad           dvd         img11   $12.99

Comment: @Mr.Bean: Maybe you haven't copied the `where t2.type = t.type` part? At least that would explain your one row result.

Comment: I have copied it and put in the correct details, but it only shows one row

Comment: This is what I am using **Select Nunca.*
from Nunca
where Nunca.id = (select max(t2.id) from Nunca t2 where Nunca.type = Nunca.type);**

Comment: @MrBean: Replace `Nunca` in **one** of the two in `Nunca.type = Nunca.type` with `t2`.

Comment: I'll give you that

Comment: @Mr.Bean . . . You have to use the table aliases.  I've adjusted the answer.  `Nunca` seems like a very unlikely name for a table, meaning "never" in Italian.